# python dict.setdefault() can't output the default value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem when I use the python dict.

```
    class Solution():
        def solve(self, A):
        lst = {}
        for i in A:
            for c in i:
                lst.setdefault(ord(c) - ord('0'), 0)
                lst[ord(c) - ord('0')] += 1
        return lst
```

But I can't output the default value

[image: Here is the output]

How can I get all the key and value in dict?

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of your terminal output, instead copy and paste the actual text into a codeblock. That way it's easier for people to read, and can be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you aren't getting all the values is because you never actually run through them. For `setdefault` to set a key, it needs to be called first, otherwise how does it know what the keys are supposed to be?

This is why in your first example, when you have no input, it outputs an empty dictionary, and in your second example, when you have the input `12`, the dictionary only contains a `1` and a `2`.

In a case where you know all possible values beforehand, I'd suggest you simply create the dictionary first, then populate it.

```
def solve(self, A):
    lst = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
    # Though a cleaner but less clear way might be:
    # lst = {key: 0 for key in range(10)}
    for i in A:
        for c in i:
            lst[ord(c) - ord('0')] += 1
            # side note you can also get the number with:
            # lst[int(c)]
```

Comment: I did suggest `dict.fromkeys(range(10), 0)` as the way to produce `{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}`.